# Frequency of professions in cities data

Tags: data-request, database, data-portal, big-data

I would like to know, is there any database out there, that will list, given a country and city, a list of professions followed by number of people working in that profession, to any degree of detail. So you could see the whole distribution of employment into particular jobs for any given city.

If so, this could help get an idea of what people did in each city, and perhaps also help decide where you wanted to go live when relocating.

Would be nice to be able to have this data also for suburbs of cities.

Thanks.

Comment: What region? in the US I would suggest http://census.gov

Comment: Any world countries would do, Americas, Europe, Asia, etc.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Can you provide a more specific link? Thanks.